# Resize an image on upload then use the move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, function, file, upload, tmp

Is there any way to resize the $_FILES["xfile1"]["tmp_name"] before I send it off to the move_uploaded_file() function? I checked every where but nobody seems to use this function after resizing the image.

ADDED*

```
// Create image from file
   switch(strtolower($_FILES['xfile1']['type']))
   {
case 'image/jpeg':
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['xfile1']['tmp_name']);
    break;
case 'image/png':
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['xfile1']['tmp_name']);
    break;
case 'image/gif':
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['xfile1']['tmp_name']);
    break;
default:
    exit('Unsupported type: '.$_FILES['xfile1']['type']);
}

 // Delete original file
 @unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

 // Target dimensions
 $max_width = 540;
 $max_height = 540;

 // Get current dimensions
 $old_width = imagesx($image);
 $old_height = imagesy($image);

// Calculate the scaling we need to do to fit the image inside our frame
$scale = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);

// Get the new dimensions
 $new_width = ceil($scale*$old_width);
 $new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);

 // Create new empty image
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);


// Resample old into new
imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 
    $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);


 ob_start();
 imagejpeg($new,'saved.jpeg' , 90);
 $data = ob_get_clean();
```

So i have this so far. I have this $data variable which i want to replace with $_FILES["xfile1"]["tmp_name"] in the move_uploaded_file() function. Is that possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You give a try........

Comment: As Vikas said - post what you've tried so far and someone will offer some help, but you will find it hard to find someone to write all your code for you.

Comment: Ok I added code of what i got so far.